# Failure to get the content of an ACC folder with folders/:folderid/contents endpoint

Tags: postman, autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I am trying to get the contents of a folder, specifically the 'Project Files' folder in ACC.

I am using postman at the moment and did the following :

- Got the Hubs,  via *projects/v1/hubs* endpoint and extracted the hubId of the desired hub
- Got the Projects, via */hubs/:hubid/projects* endpoint and extracted the projectId
- Got the TopFolders, via *hubs/hubid/projects/project_id/topFolders* endpoint, extraced the folderId
  for 'Project Files'
- Trying to get the content of the 'Project Files' content via *projects/project_id/folders/folderId/contents* and I get an error "developerMessage": "The requested resource does not exist."

The folderId I am getting is from of  "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.folder:co.bEd9KCbyQAWbhE938Cy48Q" (I changed one of the characters here)

Any ideas welcome
Thanks Jonathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out postman included a new line (i pressed the enter key) at the end of the request (%0A) ‍♂️ - please take note.
Thanks for reading and trying to help. Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a permission issue. Seems you may not have the permission to the folder contents. Kindly, see if you have the permission for Doc management service under project members to access the folder.

If you have the correct permissions, you may upgrade permission level to project admin and retry the endpoint.

Comment: Hi @Carol Gitonga
Thanks for the suggestion but this is using a 2 legged authentication , scope is set to data:read data:create and type is client_credentials . 
Jonathan

Comment: I also tried another project , just to be [almost] sure, I think it's something to do with the folderId urn format which I am missing but I don't know where to look for.